# Combine different queries with Active Record/Arel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, arel

I have a working solution on combining active record filters but I was wondering if it's possible to use just one query to make this more performant. I tried using `arel_tables` but I was unsuccessful trying to combine multiple queries using that method.

What I have at the moment is this:

```
not_accepted_ids = User.where.not(status: ['accepted', 'rejected']).pluck(:id)

accepted_ids = User.where(status: 'accepted').order('updated_at DESC').limit(25).pluck(:id)

rejected_ids = User.where(status: 'rejected').order('updated_at DESC').limit(10).pluck(:id)

@users = User.where(id: not_accepted_ids + accepted_ids + rejected_ids)
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

Since you have limits added, you cannot combine where statements. What I am getting from your query is you are trying to load 10 accepted users, 25 rejected users and all of the other users. You can load all of the users and then filter them instead.

Comment: You could use a union, but that doesn't provide much benefit. It still is roughly the same thing as before, although it is two less database round trips.